# How can I show that if the quadratic form associated with a matrix is always zero than the matrix is zero

Tags: real-analysis

How can I show that $$x'Ax=0 \,\,\,\   \forall x\in R^n$$ implies that $A=0$?
I am thinking the proper way to proceed is to come up with some method to find an $x$ for any $A\ne0$ such that $x'Ax\ne0$. However, I am having trouble doing so.

Thanks!

EDIT: $A$ actually has to be symmetric. As a counterexample, a 90 degree rotation matrix has this property. My apologies.

Comment: What would you do if the matrix were diagonal?

Comment: Clip off the $(j,j)^{th}$ entry with $x=e_j$.

Comment: Symmetric matrices can be orthogonally diagonalized. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_matrix#Decomposition

Comment: The use of symmetry is important here, otherwise $A=\begin{bmatrix}0&-1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$ would be a counterexample.  But it is possible to avoid diagonalization by expanding out $(x+y)'A(x+y) = 0$ and using symmetry to obtain $x'Ay = 0$ (a form of polarization).

Comment: Symmetry actually works fine for my application. So the full argument would be $A=Q'DQ$, $Q$ is invertible since it is orthogonal, so there is some $x \ s.t. \ Qx=e_j$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Edit: We show that $A^{T} + A = 0$. Combine with the fact $A^{T} = A$, we have $A=0$.

Proof: Motivated by the following identity:

$$ x^{T} Ay = x\cdot Ay = A^{T}x \cdot y$$

We have $$0 = (x + y) \cdot A(x+y) = x \cdot Ax + y \cdot Ay + x \cdot Ay + y \cdot Ax = x \cdot Ay + y \cdot Ax$$ So we have $$x \cdot Ay = -y \cdot Ax = -A^{T}y \cdot x = -x \cdot A^{T}y$$ Hence $$x \cdot (A+A^{T})y = 0 \quad \forall \quad x, y \in \mathbb{R}^d$$

so $A+A^{T} = 0$.

Check:

$$ a = x \cdot Ax = x^{T} A x = A^{T}x \cdot x = -Ax \cdot x = x \cdot (-Ax) = -a$$
Therefore, $a = 0 \quad \forall \quad x\in \mathbb{R}^d$.

Comment: I believe that by [quadratic form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_form) it is meant that $A^T=A$.

Comment: @julien You are right so A = 0 in this case.